# How can I get package size (Application, .pkg, etc')?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am trying to get the package size of packages stored locally on my computer, for example, for every item in the `Applications` directory.

I'm able to get sizes when using the below, but for files only, and not packages.

I know I can enumerate thru the package itself, and add the sizes of all the files contained within that package, just like with standard directory,
But this is too much performance expensive for me,

And since, when going to the `Applications` directory and clicking on every app, you instantly get the package size, without having to wait several seconds/minutes for the calculations of several GBs apps,
I'm certain that this 'package size' value is stored someplace, I just can't find where and how can I access it.

So far I have tried to following, which works perfectly for getting the sizes for files.
Note that `self.url` is an `NSURL` property of the item's path.

```
    NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:[self.url path] error:nil];
    NSString *fileSize = [attributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
    NSLog(@"%@", fileSize);
    // Always returns 102

    NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:[self.url path]];
    unsigned long long fisize = [fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
    NSLog(@"%lld", fisize);
    // Always return 0

    // All of the below always return NULL
    id value = nil;
    [self.url getResourceValue:&value forKey:NSURLFileSizeKey error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", value);

    [self.url getResourceValue:&value forKey:NSURLFileAllocatedSizeKey error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", value);

    [self.url getResourceValue:&value forKey:NSURLTotalFileAllocatedSizeKey error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", value);

    [self.url getResourceValue:&value forKey:NSURLTotalFileSizeKey error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", value);
```

Any ideas guys?

Comment: If I go to Applications folder and browse apps, bearing in mind that I probably haven't specifically ever done that on this machine before, and certainly not since restart, I have to wait a few seconds for several of the sizes to calculate. Have you considered using a command line tool, perhaps `du`?

Comment: @Wain, thanks for the command line suggestion mate, but getting the package size is not the end goal, I then need to use it in my app. And that is what I meant, the first time it does some calculations, but after that first time, you receive the file instantly, meaning the OS stores that attribute someplace. Any other ideas mate?

Comment: I'd guess the finder caches the size and possibly monitors for changes with the event queue. It is just a guess though.

Answer (score 0):

Quite late to the party... but maybe helpful to others too

```
/*
 sizeOfObjectAtURL:

 */
+ (unsigned long long)sizeOfObjectAtURL:(NSURL *)pURL {

    unsigned long long  size = 0;

    NSNumber*   fileSizeValue = nil;
    NSError*    error = nil;
    BOOL        success = [pURL getResourceValue:&fileSizeValue
                                    forKey:NSURLFileSizeKey
                                        error:&error];
    if (fileSizeValue) {
        size = fileSizeValue.longLongValue;
    }
    else if (success) {
        NSNumber*   isPackageValue = nil;
        success = [pURL getResourceValue:&isPackageValue
                                  forKey:NSURLIsPackageKey
                                   error:&error];
        NSNumber*   isDirectoryValue = nil;
        success = [pURL getResourceValue:&isDirectoryValue
                                  forKey:NSURLIsDirectoryKey
                                   error:&error];
        if ((isPackageValue.boolValue) ||
            (isDirectoryValue.boolValue)) {
            NSArray<NSURL*>* contents = [NSFileManager.defaultManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:pURL
                                                                    includingPropertiesForKeys:@[NSURLFileSizeKey]
                                                                                       options:0
                                                                                         error:&error];
            for (NSURL* itemURL in contents) {
                size += [self sizeOfObjectAtURL:itemURL];
            }
        }
        else {
            // Unknown problem
        }
    }

    return size;
}
```